# Transitions with css

Tags: css

I am working on giving style to my menu, I really am something new in this

What I try to do is that when my menu appears it will see a transition from left to right, when it is hidden from it will be hidden from the left

I am really learning how to work with style sheets, I search the web and I have not managed to make it work as I wish

```
@media (max-width: 828px) {
      #menu-header.show {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
      #menu-header {
        display: block ;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: #FFF;
        left: 0;
        top: 100px;
        height: -webkit-calc(100% - 50px);
        height: -moz-calc(100% - 50px);
        height: calc(100% - 50px);
        width: 90%;
        padding: 20px 20px;
        max-width: 87.5%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        -webkit-transition: all 350ms ease;
        -moz-transition: all 350ms ease;
        -ms-transition: all 350ms ease;
        -o-transition: all 350ms ease;
        transition: all 350ms ease;
        }
```

Some example where you can help me to solve my problem, since my menu currently makes a transition from top to bottom, and what I am looking for is from left to right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var header = document.getElementById('menu-header');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    header.classList.toggle('show');
});
```

```css
@media (max-width: 828px) {
  #menu-header {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #FFF;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: transform 350ms ease;
    background: #c33;
  }
  
  #menu-header.show {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

#button {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-header">
  MENU
</div>

<button id="button">
  Click me
</button>
```